# Get td value when clicking the td row. MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, model-view-controller

I have a prblem with fetching the right value from a Td element. I can get the first element in the table when im clicking on that element but no other row is working. My code is looking like this:

```
<div id="Users">
                    <table id="UserTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th name="id">ID</th>
                                <th name="UserName">Användarnamn</th>
                                <th>Installation</th>
                                <th>Säljföretag</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var users in Model.AdminUsers)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="userId">@users.Id</td>
                                    <td id="userName" >
                                        <a id="userIds"href="#backdropreport" class="">@users.UserName </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>@users.InstallationId</td>
                                    <td>@users.MerchantId</td>
                                </tr>

                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

And my Jquery code:

```
            $("#userName").click(function () {
               var id = $("#userId").text();
               $("#user").val(id);
        });
```

Model content dialog

```
<div id="backdropreport">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="header">
        <h3>Återställ lösenord</h3>
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Users", FormMethod.Post)) 
    {
        <div class="copy">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="m-form-item">
                    För att återställa lösenordet så tryck på återställ så kommer ett mail skickas med ett nytt lösenord 
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="m-form-item">
                    <input type="submit" id="reset" value="Återställ" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    <a id="close" href="#" class="btn btn-grey">Stäng</a>
                </div>
                    <div class="m-form-item">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <input type="text" id="user" name="user"  />

        </div>
    }
</div>
<a href="#"><div class="overlay"></div></a>
```

The thing i want to do is to fetch the id of a specific td element when a user is clicking on the username. At the moment just the first element in the table is working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `id` is supposed to be unique through the whole DOM document. You can use classes instead, and use the `.class` selector.

```html
@foreach (var users in Model.AdminUsers) {
  <tr>
    <td class="userId">@users.Id</td>
    <td class="userName">
      <a class="userIds" href="#backdropreport">@users.UserName</a>
    </td>
    <td>@users.InstallationId</td>
    <td>@users.MerchantId</td>
  </tr>
}
```

```js
$(".userName").click(function() {
  var userId = $(this).siblings(".userId").text();
  alert(userId);
});
```

Comment: The id i want to fetch here is "userId" and that id is unique

Comment: @AndreasJangefalk You're iterating with a `@foreach` loop, so several `td` elements with a same `id` may be generated.

Comment: Opps sorry didn't see that. Thank you. And how would the Jquery code look like then?

Comment: @AndreasJangefalk It's the class selector: https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: okey i i add the class selector i get all the ids at the samt time. But same as before only if i click at the first element in the table list. The other element doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Html attribute "id" should be unique, but when you're doing foreach loop, then in all rows < td > element has id="userId". I would recommend you adding userId to html id attribute:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var users in Model.AdminUsers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td id="userId_@users.Id">@users.Id</td>
            <td id="userName_@users.Id" >
                <a id="userIds"href="#backdropreport" class="">@users.UserName </a>
            </td>
            <td>@users.InstallationId</td>
            <td>@users.MerchantId</td>
        </tr>

    }
</tbody>
```